# How to fix this getIdFieldName fatal error in magento?

Tags: php, magento

I am new to magento. I am trying to write module to report abuse about site.I have the form on below page.

```
http://localhost/magento/vendorinfo/page/report/
```

Module name is vendorinfo, controller is page and action is report. Below is my `ReportAction` which has taken from my Venderinfo module

```
    public function reportsubmitAction() {
       $data = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
 try {

            $insert_data = array();
            $insert_data['reporter_name']    = $data['name'];
            $insert_data['reporter_email']   = $data['email'];
            $insert_data['report_category']  = $data['category_type'];
            $insert_data['reporter_comment'] = $data['report_comments'];


            $model = Mage::getModel('vendorinfo/report'); 
            $model->setData($insert_data)->setId(null);  // i have got the error on this line
            $model->setCreatedTime(now())->setUpdateTime(now());
            $model->save();

            Mage::getSingleton('frontend/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('articles')->__('Report was successfully submitted'));
            Mage::getSingleton('frontend/session')->setFormData(false);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::getSingleton('frontend/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
            Mage::getSingleton('frontend/session')->setFormData($data);
            $this->_redirect('vendorinfo/page/report', array());
            return;
        }

    }
```

When i submit the form i called the above action to store my data to DB. But i 've got this below error,

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getIdFieldName() on a
>   non-object in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Abstract.php on
>   line 151

Also i have create the 2 model files under the following folder structure,

**1. Venderinfo/Model/Report.php**

```
class Comp_Vendorinfo_Model_Report extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    public function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->_init('vendorinfo/report_abuse');

    }
}
```

**2.Venderinfo/Model/Mysql4/Report/Collection.php**

```
   class Comp_Vendorinfo_Model_Mysql4_Report_Collection extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Collection_Abstract
    {
        public function _construct()
        {
            parent::_construct();
            $this->_init('vendorinfo/report_abuse');
        }
    }
```

What i done wrong on this?

Kindly advice on this.

Comment: if you magento version is >= 1.6 it would be better to use Resource not Mysql4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a resource model `Venderinfo/Model/Mysql4/Report.php` and declare it in your config. In your database table, you should have an ID field such as `report_id`, and this name must be defined in the constructor of the resource model.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-5-magento-models-and-orm-basics

Answer (score 1):

Kindly go to magento root file->app/etc
And Check local.xml file
if this is not available here kindly copy local.xml another magento directory and edit & copy here.

Problem are resolved